# Magento, Override local controller with other local controller

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-1.9

I am trying to override local codepool extension controller with the other local extension, but its not working, don't know the reason, `firstextension` is the extension I want to override by `secondextension`

here is my code

`config.xml`

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <firstextension>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Namespace_secondextension before="Namespace_Firstextension">Namespace_secondextension_Adminhtml</Namespace_secondextension>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </firstextension>

    </routers>
</admin>
```

and `controller`

```
<?php

  require_once 'local/Namespace/Firstextension/controllers/Adminhtml/CustomController.php';
  class Namespace_Secondextension_Adminhtml_CustomController extends Namespace_Firstextension_Adminhtml_CustomController
  {
      public function saveAction()
      { 
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 require_once 'local/Namespace/Firstextension/controllers/Adminhtml/CustomController.php';
```

to

```
 require_once 'Namespace/Firstextension/controllers/Adminhtml/CustomController.php';
```

**proper way :**

```
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Namespace_Firstextension').DS.Adminhtml.DS.'CustomController.php';
```

Also,need to change in

```
<Namespace_secondextension before="Namespace_Firstextension">Namespace_secondextension_Adminhtml</Namespace_secondextension>
```

you need to change  from  `Namespace_secondextension_Adminhtml`  to `Namespace_Secondextension`

Comment: Already tried this

Comment: still not working

Comment: And `require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Namespace_Firstextension').DS.Adminhtml.DS.'CustomController.php';`
to 
`require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Namespace_Firstextension').DS.'Adminhtml'.DS.'CustomController.php';` :)